# Inserting into LocalDB Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012-localdb

I have a problem that I couldn't find a solution to it, which is inserting data to LocalDB in Visual Studio `Windows Form App - C#`
Actually, I'm using a Class Library, and I added a reference to it in my Windows Form app 
The problem is when I want to add new data to the local db, it doesn't show any errors, however, I see no data inserted into the database

This is my code in the Class Library, which is a general method the could be used to add any data to any table in the database

```
    public virtual void Add(Item item)
    {
        int count = 0;
        //create the first part of the Add SQL string
        string addString = "INSERT INTO " + table + "(";

        //add each field name from Item UpdateFields to the string
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> field in item.UpdateFields)
        {
            addString += "[" + field.Key + "]";
            count++;
            //add a comma when end of UpdateFields collection is reached
            if (count < item.UpdateFields.Count)
            { addString += ", "; }

        }

        //start second part of Add string
        addString += ") VALUES(";
        count = 0;
        //add each value from Item UpdateFields to the string
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> field in item.UpdateFields)
        {
            if (field.Value != null)
            { addString += "'" + field.Value.ToString() + "'"; }
            else
            { addString += "NULL"; }
            count++;
            //add a comma when end of UpdateFields collection is reached
            if (count < item.UpdateFields.Count)
            { addString += ", "; }
        }
        //add bracket at end of Add string
        addString += ")";

        command.CommandText = addString;

        try
        {
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            item.Valid = false;
            item.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
        }


    }
```

and here where I'm using it to add an Account information

```
cc = new Account(accountID);
acc.UserName = userNametxt.Text;
acc.Password = "P@ssword";
acc.Email = emailtxt.Text;
acc.CreatedBy = "";
acc.Status = "1";
acc.LastLoginDateTime = null;
acc.LastFailureLoginDateTime = null;
accounts.Add(acc);
if (!acc.Valid)
{
  MessageBox.Show(acc.ErrorMessage);
}
else
{
  MessageBox.Show("Account has been added successfully!!");
}
```

and the following is my string connection

```
new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TestConnectionString);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the part of the code where you create the Command. Also, beware that you must use parameters instead of string concatenation, or risk an SQL Injection attack

Comment: command = connection.CreateCommand();
            command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM " + table;
            reader = command.ExecuteReader();

Comment: this is how i use the command

Comment: No, it ins't. You are showing a command to SELECT data, and you are looking for errors in an INSERT. Without precise info none can help. Also, include your connection string, not the property from where it's loaded.

Comment: i have already copied the insert in my question, and about the connecting i am using it like this because when changing it to the path many errors occurred and using such statement solved them